# Passing an entire object through Action Link

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to pass an entire object from my view to my controller. In my for each the address is populated as expected however I am struggling to pass this complete object back to my controller method "EditPlusNewAddress".

```
@if (Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        <table border="1" cellpadding="1">
            @foreach (var address in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@address.postcode</td>
                    <td>@address.lat</td>
                    <td>@address.lng</td>
                    <td>@address.thorofare</td>
                    <td>@address.dthorofare</td>
                    <td>@address.county</td>
                    <td>@address.paon</td>
                    <td>@address.saon</td>
                    <td>@address.posttown</td>
                    <td>@address.uprn</td>   
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Select Address", "EditPlusNewAddress", new { evpId = 11}, new JsonAddressModel{ county = address.county,
                                                                                                                          dthorofare = address.dthorofare,
                                                                                                                          ExtensionData = address.ExtensionData,
                                                                                                                          lat = address.lat,
                                                                                                                          lng = address.lng,
                                                                                                                          paon = address.paon,
                                                                                                                          postcode = address.postcode,
                                                                                                                          posttown = address.posttown,
                                                                                                                          saon = address.saon,
                                                                                                                          thorofare = address.thorofare,
                                                                                                                           uprn = address.uprn}, null)</td>             
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }
```

I'm getting the following errors:

> Error 2   Argument 4: cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'string'
>
> Error 3   Argument 5: cannot convert from
>   'Solution.Core.AddressService.JsonAddressModel' to
>   'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary'
>
> Error 1   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper>'
>   does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and the best extension
>   method overload
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   string, string, string, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary)' has some
>   invalid arguments

Comment: Why would you want to post all that data back to the server when it's not needed? It looks like it's originally coming from the server so you just need to post back some sort of identifier.

Comment: The service I'm getting the address from only accepts a postcode and returns a list of relevant addresses for that postcode. Which im outputting to a table with a link for each one. My intention is for when that link is clicked the new address will populate the new address boxes on my original form

Comment: Your errors are related to the [actionLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx) overload you are trying to use. The parameters you are using does not match one of the overloads and it points out exactly which overload it considers a best match `System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(HtmlHelper, string, string, string, RouteValueDictionary, IDictionary)`.

Comment: Keep in mind with `ActionLink` you'll be passing your values back on the URL as a GET request.

Comment: Yeh my plan was to get the original object from the database, and populate some additional properties from the newly selected address

Comment: Mirroring DavidG's comment: If all of these addresses are in your database, and if you have an id for each distinct address, even if the user needs to specify an additional info all you ever need to pass back is that row id. After returning back to the server you get all the details back in your controller action from the database.

Comment: Assuming just an id is not possible, you'll need to either populate and submit a form or send that object back as an AJAX request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't pass objects back from a view, we pass name:value combinations and   build a model from that on the server:

In this case all you need is an `[HttpGet]` action on your controller accepting a `JsonAddressModel` parameter

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditPlusNewAddress(JsonAddressModel model)
{
    ....
}
```

Then in your view you pass up the values you want to use. Here the error message should have given you the clue, as you're simply using the wrong type of object... a `JsonAddressModel` instead of a `RouteValueDictionary`.

This is because you went a position to far in your ActionLink definition. So assuming evpId is the Identifier for you `JsonAddressModel` it should have just been:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Select Address", "EditPlusNewAddress",
                         new { evpId = 11 ,
                             county = address.county,
                             dthorofare = address.dthorofare,
                             ExtensionData = address.ExtensionData,
                             lat = address.lat,
                             lng = address.lng,
                             paon = address.paon,
                             postcode = address.postcode,
                             posttown = address.posttown,
                             saon = address.saon,
                             thorofare = address.thorofare,
                             uprn = address.uprn
                         })
```

That would be how you build up an url that looked like:

```
/Controller/EditPlusNewAddress?evpId=11&county=burbank&dthorofare=abc&......
```

The model binder is then smart enough to take the query string and build a `JsonAddressModel` out of it. So that would be how you *could* pass around a complex url for sharing search filters, etc.

The problem however is `GET` is supposed to be an idempotent operation. Whereas you're calling your action "EditPlusNewAddress" which sounds like you want to change something server side and for that, good practice dictates, that you should be creating a form and `POSTing` it back.

`GET` links that change things reeks of malware, evil doers and/or incompetence.

Comment: Evpid is a sepreate id relating to thw main view, the person that we are looking for a new address. The only unique id in the jsonaddressmodel is the uprn, which can sonetimes be blank or null

Comment: @SelectDistinct Well either way that's how you "pass an object through an ActionLink". You can do a public ActionResult EditPlusNewAddress(string evpId, JsonAddressModel model) if it better suits your purposes as the model binder is smart enough to work it out.